# Media keys stop working after wake from sleep

Tags: shortcut-keys, google-chrome, 18.10

I use chrome to listen to music via Google Play Music. And I can use the media keys (play, next, etc) on my keyboard. But whenever I wake the laptop from sleep those keys stop working (ubuntu displays the crossed out circle icon on the screen). If I restart chrome they start working again.

Same problem happens if I use [Google Play Music Desktop Player](https://www.googleplaymusicdesktopplayer.com/). So I assume it's a chrome bug of some sort.

Is there a way to run something on login that would force Chrome to re-register the keyboard shortcuts, but without restarting the whole browser?

I've got an XPS 13 if that makes any difference.

Comment: If it happens only with Chrome and Google apps and knowing Chrome and Google are proprietary software filling a bug report with Google is what you can do. Bug reports are off-topic here.

Comment: It's not a bug report (I can fill that separately, and I will). I'm looking for a workaround here.

Comment: Again, proprietary software...

Comment: I don't understand how that matters? Either there is a workaround or there isn't.

Comment: This question seems reasonable to me. The policy about bug reports is meant to be applied with... nuance.

Comment: @Zana it does not solve the problem